# Modify value of an XML element in foreach loop using simpleXML in php

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

I want to modify XML values (of the file) using simpleXML in a foreach loop.

My XML look like that :

```
<a>
<b id="first">
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
</b>
<b id="second">
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
</b>
<b id="third">
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
</b>
```

And my php look like that :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('myfile.xml');
$idOfB = 'first'; // the id of b and I want to modify the children nodes of that

foreach($xml->a->b as $node) {

    foreach($node->attributes() as $id => $value) {
        if((string)$value == $idOfB) {
            // Something there I guess...
                    // I want to change the value of c and d of this node
        }
    }
}

$xml->asXML();
```

I have tried and searched quite a lot without any luck.

Comment: Do you want to modify xml file or only xml object?

Comment: I want to modify the xml file

Comment: Try this $xml->asXML('myfile.xml');

Comment: Ok, thank you. My main problem is to modify c and d.

Comment: You want to add something b/w <c>Hello</c> tags?

Answer (score 4):

Your testing file suppose to be like ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
<b id="first">
    <c>Abhishek</c>
    <d/>
</b>
<b id="second">
    <c/>
    <d/>
</b>
<b id="third">
    <c/>
    <d/>
</b>
</a>
```

---

here abhishek will be replaced by Nishant

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("testingxml.xml");
$idOfB = 'first'; // the id of b and I want to modify the children nodes of that

foreach($xml->b as $node) {

    foreach($node->attributes() as $id => $value) {

        if((string)$value == $idOfB) {

            $node->c = 'Nishant';
            $node->d = 'Tyagi';
            // Something there I guess...
                    // I want to change the value of c and d of this node
        }
    }

    //$finobjArr[] = $node;
}
//$xmlobj = $finobjArr;

file_put_contents("testingxml.xml", $xml->saveXML());
////$xml->asXML("testingxml.xml");
//print($xml->asXML("testingxml.xml"));
?>
```